# Партнёрская ссылка: редирект, или сразу?

Tags: веб-программирование

Как лучше реализовать механизм для партнёрской/реферал ссылки?
Не сталкивался раньше, понадобилось быстро выкатить сразу на продакшн.

Два варианта пока в голове:

1. приходит очередной посетитель с get-параметром `?utm_source=VasyaInviter` (его и Яндекс с Гуглом поймут заодно). Если ещё нет, получает куки `invitedBy=VasyaInviter`, в БД попадает запись о том, какой молодец Vasya.
2. реферальный трафик гнать на спец. url типа `site.ru/ref/VasyaInviter`, там обрабатывать, проставлять куки и перекидывать на главную страницу.

Как Вы думаете, лучше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично я бы выбрал первый вариант. Во-первых, сразу видно на какую страницу переходишь. Во-вторых, это работает более прозрачно.

Answer (score 1):

Яндекс с Гуглом не поймут `utm_source` если вы будете сразу делать редирект. Чтобы вы увидели в статистике переходы с этим параметром нужно чтобы страница со счётчиками загрузилась до отправки данных в базы Яндекса и Гугла.

Потому у вас нет какого-то другого второго варианта. Только первый.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/204047)

Comment: @elik вы вопрос-то читали? чем вам мой ответ не ответом кажется?